# C/C++ Code and LIBRARY Mixing

Tags: c++, opencv, opencl, tbb

I’m a native C++ programmer never knew anything about low level C, due to some circumstances I had to use C extensively. The outcome was me catching on a lot of C habits.
Know I’m trying to develop some Computer Vision project  using OpenCV, TBB, OpenCL and OpenGL.

The thing is OpenCL is native C, so is TBB I guess not 100% sure about the TBB. As everybody knows C++ is an industrial Language and so Developing in it is a blast(at least for me) but after doing the main Which language should I use research? I’m know more concerned with C/C++ Code MIXING….

So my question is this Should I Develop the whole thing in C (Hard to maintain, expand and develop with) or should I stay with C++. And if I’m staying with C++ can someone plz direct me to a good way, strategy(Book, Tutorial) of mixing C/C++.
Thanks in advance.....

Comment: In fact, TBB is a C++ library, and it heavily uses templates. Though it can be irrelevant if you only mentioned it because it is used by OpenCV.

Answer (score 4):

All the technologies you mention have C++ APIs. So if you are already comfortable using that, by all means do so. There does not need to be any mixing of C and C++ in one file, at all.

Only the OpenCL kernels are written in plain (OpenCL-) C. You do not mix the code, but you may have to pass data from your C++ code to your OpenCL kernel. Since you mention you now know both, that should not be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

This C++ faq lite entry should be helpful. [Mixing C and CPP](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html)